# R Programming: Calculate two-sample t-test for a data frame with formatting

Tags: r

Good evening,
I have the following data frame:

```
Sex A  B  C D  E
M   1 20 45 42 12
F   2 10 32 23 43
M   39 32 2 23 43
M   24 43 2 44 12
F   11 3 4 4 11
```

How would I calculate the two-sample t-test for each numerical variable for the data frame listed above by the sex variable by using the apply function. The result should be a matrix that contains five
columns: F.mean (mean of the numerical variable for Female), M.mean (mean of the numerical variable
for Male), t (for t-statistics), df (for degrees of freedom), and p (for p-value).

Thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried already? A t.test object contains all of that information

Comment: The OP's problem is one of subsetting within the apply function the code, t.test(data.set[data.set[,1] == "F",]$A, data.set[data.set[,1] == "M",]$A) works for A but it's tricky to get that to work across A:E using an apply function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `apply` with margin `2`

```
out = apply(data[,-1], 2, function(x){ 
            unlist(t.test(x[data$Sex == 'M'], x[data$Sex == 'F'])[c(1:3,5)],
            recursive=FALSE)
       })

#> out
#                            A           B           C          D          E
#statistic.t         1.2432059  3.35224633 -0.08318328  1.9649783 -0.2450115
#parameter.df        2.5766151  2.82875770  2.70763487  1.9931486  1.8474695
#p.value             0.3149294  0.04797862  0.93946696  0.1887914  0.8309453
#estimate.mean of x 21.3333333 31.66666667 16.33333333 36.3333333 22.3333333
#estimate.mean of y  6.5000000  6.50000000 18.00000000 13.5000000 27.0000000
```

**data**

```
data = structure(list(Sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, 2L, 39L, 24L, 11L), B = c(20L, 
10L, 32L, 43L, 3L), C = c(45L, 32L, 2L, 2L, 4L), D = c(42L, 23L, 
23L, 44L, 4L), E = c(12L, 43L, 43L, 12L, 11L)), .Names = c("Sex", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: what does unlist do?

Comment: `unlist` simplifies the list to produce a vector, read `?unlist` for more

Comment: Puzzled where the list came from then realised that the t.test output is a list ... d'ugh!!!

Answer (score 1):

should be a combination of apply, t.test and aggregate, I think. But first turn the row names into a names colums. Then you can do subsetting with aggregate and then apply with t.test

Comment: I took the Sex to be a column, structure(list(Sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), A = c(1, 2, 39, 24, 11), B = c(20, 10, 
32, 43, 3), D = c(45, 32, 2, 2, 4), E = c(12, 43, 43, 12, 11)), .Names = c("Sex", 
"A", "B", "D", "E"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")